# Why -INT_MIN is NOT 2147483648 for uint64_t type

Tags: c++

I understand the results of `p`. Could someone please explain why `up2 (uint64_t type) != 2147483648`  but `up (uint32_t type) == 2147483648` ?

Some mention that assigning -INT_MIN to unsigned integer up2 will cause overflow, but

1. `-INT_MIN` is already a positive number, so it is fine to assign it to `uint64_t up2`?
2. Why it seems to be ok to assign `-INT_MIN` to `uint32_t up`? It produces correct result as 2147483648.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <climits>

   using namespace std;

   int main() {
       int n = INT_MIN;
       int p = -n;
       uint32_t up = -n;
       uint64_t up2 = -n;

       cout << "n: " << n << endl;
       cout << "p: " << p << " up: " << up << " up2: " << up2 << endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   n: -2147483648
   p: -2147483648 //because -INT_MIN = INT_MIN for signed integer
   up: 2147483648 //because up is unsigned int from 0 to 4,294,967,295 (2^32 − 1) and can cover 2147483648

   up2: 18446744071562067968  //Question here. WHY up2 != up (2147483648)???
   ```

Comment: `INT_MAX` **is not** 2147483648. It is 2147483647 (in your implementation).

Comment: thanks. I already updated my question

Comment: 8 bits gives you 255 maximum, 16 bits gives you 65535 maximum, 32 bits gives you 4294967295, 64 bits would give you a very bit number :)

Comment: @SPlatten 18,446,744,073,709,551,616

Comment: Undefined behavior is so dangerous especially because it _seems to be ok_ in many cases.

Answer (score 7):

The behaviour of `int p = -n;` is *undefined* on a 2's complement system (accepting that you have a typo in your question; `INT_MAX` is always odd on such a system), due to your overflowing an `int` type. So your entire program is undefined.

This is why you see `INT_MIN` defined as `-INT_MAX - 1` in many libraries.

Comment: While correct this does not address OP's question about the value for `up2`

Comment: Isn't just undefined?  If you know the system is two's-compliment then it wouldn't be undefined because you know how it will behave?

Comment: @Bathsheba Could you please explain the up2 ?

Comment: @coder It's undefined. The `n` in `-n` is an int ,so it will overflow. The same evaluation on `-n` is performed in `uint64_t up2 = -n` and in `int p = -n`; The type (int or uint64) of the variable you store the result in does not affect the evaluation of the subexpression `-n`. (But as this is undefined behavior, you could get different result that does or does not make sense)

Comment: @coder: Bad things will happen to me if I try to explain something that's undefined.

Comment: @nos  but why assigning `-n` to `uint32_t up` works?

Comment: @coder It does not "work". It is undefined behavior. Just because it shows the number you expected does not mean it is without issues. You could assign -n to uint32_t like that another place in the code, or with other options to your compiler , or with another version of the compiler etc., and it could give you another value.

Answer (score 4):

Note that while you invoke undefined behavior due to signed integer overflow, here is the most likely explanation for the behavior you are observing:

If `int` is 32 bits on your system, and your system uses one's complement or two's complement for signed integer storage, then the sign bit will be extended into the upper 32-bits of a 64 bit unsigned type.

It may make more sense if you print out your values in base-16 instead.

```
n = 0x80000000
p = 0x80000000
up = 0x80000000
up2 = 0xFFFFFFFF80000000
```

Comment: this is dangerous because it could change behavior at any time.   Code around it changing could change the behavior.   Changing compilers could change it.   Changing the environment you're compiling for could change it.

Comment: @xaxxon Like I said, OP has undefined behavior. My answer only delved into the specifics on his system.

Answer (score 2):

What you see is `-n` converted to an `uint64`, where the overflow is not on 4 billion, but 2**64:

```
18446744073709551616 - 2147483648 = 18446744071562067968
```

Comment: Because for `unit32_t`, it is 4 billions. It's basic math. 2^32 - 2^31 = 2^31.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `-n` in your case causes **undefined behavior**, since the result cannot fit into the range of `int` data type. (Whether or not you assign this *undefined* result to a variable of "wider" type doesn't matter at all, the inversion itself is made with `int`.)

Trying to explain undefined behavior makes no sense.

Comment: It's likely to be dangerous and/or unhelpful for solving a given problem to try and explain UB, but (especially without compiler optimizations) one may still learn something from understanding why a given behavior manifests.